# Bootstrap carousel inside Google Maps Infobox

Tags: javascript, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3, infobox

I'm using Bootstrap in my website and I have created a map with multiple markers using google maps api v3 (javascript). I'd like to have an image carousel in each marker's infowindow. In order to be able to have control over the infowindow styling, I'm using the [Infobox addon](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html).

The problem is that carousel is not working inside Infobox. Please check this demo:

http://liveweave.com/MourQl

Could you help me fix this? 
Is there some kind of incompatibility between JQuery and Infobox?

Here's the js code that creates the map:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {

        var locations = [
          ['<h4>Bondi Beach</h4>', -33.890542, 151.274856],
          ['<h4>Maroubra Beach</h4>', -33.950198, 151.259302]
        ];

        var content = [
          ['<div id="carousel-example-1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false"><div class="carousel-inner"><div class="item active"><img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/25g70g9.jpg" alt=""></div><div class="item"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/ddgoia.jpg" alt="..."></div><div class="item"><img src="http://i58.tinypic.com/b3ws5c.jpg" alt="..."></div></div><a class="prev carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-1" role="button" data-slide="prev"></a><a class="next carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-1" role="button" data-slide="next"></a></div>'],
          ['<div id="carousel-example-2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false"><div class="carousel-inner"><div class="item active"><img src="http://i60.tinypic.com/25g70g9.jpg" alt=""></div><div class="item"><img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/ddgoia.jpg" alt="..."></div><div class="item"><img src="http://i58.tinypic.com/b3ws5c.jpg" alt="..."></div></div><a class="prev carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-2" role="button" data-slide="prev"></a><a class="next carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-2" role="button" data-slide="next"></a></div>']
        ];

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-container'), {
          zoom: 10,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.92, 151.25),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          streetViewControl: false,
          panControl: false,
          zoomControlOptions: {
             position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
          }
        });

        var markers = new Array();

        //var iconCounter = 0;
        var markerImg = 'http://i58.tinypic.com/dr9o5j.png';
        var activeMarkerImg = 'http://i58.tinypic.com/w6ph7c.png';


        // Add the markers and infowindows to the map
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
              map: map,
              icon: markerImg
          });

          markers.push(marker);

            var myOptions = {
             content: content[i][0]
            ,disableAutoPan: false
            ,maxWidth: 0
            ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-125, -250)
            ,zIndex: null
            ,boxStyle: { 
              width: "250px"
             }
            ,closeBoxMargin: "0"
            ,closeBoxURL: ""
            ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
            ,isHidden: false
            ,pane: "floatPane"
            ,enableEventPropagation: false
        };

        var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);



        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
          jQuery('.carousel').carousel();
          ib.open(map, this);
          jQuery('.carousel').carousel();
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(ib, 'domready', function() {
            jQuery('.carousel').carousel();  

        });

        //ib.open(map, marker);


        }
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {ib.close();});


        function AutoCenter() {
          //  Create a new viewpoint bound
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          //  Go through each...
          $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
            bounds.extend(marker.position);
          });
          //  Fit these bounds to the map
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
        AutoCenter();

    }
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).on('load', function () {
    //map initialize
    initialize();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're still having this issue, but for anyone else having trouble, it seems that infobox disables child events. You need to add the event separately once the infobox has been loaded.

```
infoWindow: function(content, map, marker) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            // If there is an open infobox on the screen, close it out
            if (ib) {
                ib.close();
            }

            ib.setContent($('.unitInfoBox').clone().html());
            ib.open(map, marker);

            // Once the infobox is fully loaded, add your events here
            ib.addListener('domready', function() {
                // Set up the carousel for images
                $('#unitImageContainer').carousel({
                    interval: false
                });

                // Specify what you want the carousel to do when the .carousel-indicator is clicked
                $('.carousel-indicators li').click(function() {
                    $('#unitImageContainer').carousel(parseInt($(this).attr('data-slide-to')));
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small edit to make work also carousel arrows:

```
  infoWindow: function(content, map, marker) {
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
              // If there is an open infobox on the screen, close it out
              if (ib) {
                  ib.close();
              }

              ib.setContent($('.unitInfoBox').clone().html());
              ib.open(map, marker);

              // Once the infobox is fully loaded, add your events here
              ib.addListener('domready', function() {
                  // Set up the carousel for images
                  $('#unitImageContainer').carousel({
                      interval: false
                  });

                  // Specify what you want the carousel to do when the .carousel-indicator is clicked
                  $('.carousel-indicators li').click(function() {
                      $('#unitImageContainer').carousel(parseInt($(this).attr('data-slide-to')));
                  });
                  // Arrows fix
                  $('.carousel-control').click(function() {
                    $('.map-thumbs').carousel($(this).attr('data-slide'));
                  });
              });
          });
      }
```

Comment: If you having JS fiddle examples just give it here it will helpful.